# nil:NilClass (NoMethodError) Error

Tags: ruby

When I run my code I get the following:

```
cities.rb:70:in `sell_is_valid': undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    from cities.rb:103
    from cities.rb:79:in `each'
    from cities.rb:79
```

Here is the code for that:

```
def sell_is_valid(num, type)
    puts "The most loads of #{type} you can sell is #{@train[num]}." #Line 66
    puts "How many #{type} would you like to sell?"
    prompt; value = gets.chomp.to_i
    if @train[num] <= value
        @wallet = @wallet + (value * @cities[@current_location][num]) #Line 70
        @storage = @storage + value
        @train[num] = @train[num] - value
    else
        puts "You're trying to buy too much!"
    end
end
```

So then what I did was did a puts on line 70.

```
puts @wallet
puts @cities[@current_location][num]
```

Same error this time on the  puts @cities[@current_location][num] line. So I know that is what is making it do this. However, I use that line all through my code. For example, do the to the flow of my game (you have to buy something before you can sell it) that exact same line is executed three times in the buy_is_valid function with no issues. I also did a puts on num and it is giving me a valid number. It also is being used correctly in line 66.

Any ideas on how to track this down?

***EDIT***

```
p @cities
p @current_location
```

returns

```
{:new_york=>[2, 25, 12], :chicago=>[18, 12, 2], :dallas=>[16, 12, 4], :omaha=>[16, 5, 5], :seattle=>[2, 29, 16]}
"new_york"
```

Comment: `@current_location` is "new_york" but your keys in `@cities` are all symbols (i.e., `:new_york`).  Convert @current_location to a symbol when indexing, maybe?  `@cities[@current_location.to_sym]...`

Comment: @baaron, It appears that fixed it. Off to research symbols!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is saying, that you're calling `[]` on `nil`. Since in the expression `@cities[@current_location][num]`, you're first calling `[]` on `@cities` and then on the result of `@cities[@current_location]`, this means that either `@cities` or `@cities[@current_location]` is `nil`.

To find out which one is the case, you should trying printing out `@cities` and `@current_location` using `p @cities, @current_location`. If `@cities` is `nil`, that's the reason for the error. If it isn't it should now at least be apparent why `@current_location` isn't a valid key for it.

Comment: Is it true that if @cities isn't nil, then it has to be @current_location? I did the p on each and they returned valid (non-nil) statements. See my edit to the original question for the results.

Comment: @Noah: No, as a matter of fact if `@cities` were nil, that would not cause this error message. As I said: If `@cities` is not nil, then `@cities[@current_location]` is nil, which means that `@current_location` is not present as a key in `@cities` (or not a valid index for `@cities` if `@cities` is an array). If you print both `@cities` and `@current_location` using `p`, it should become apparent, why `@current_location` is not a valid key/index.

Comment: @Noah: As your edit shows, `@current_location` is `"new_york"`, which is not a key that appears in `@cities` (`:new_york` does, but that's not the same value). You should either convert `@current_location` to a symbol or change `@cities` to use strings as keys instead of symbols.

Comment: Thanks. Baron posted a comment to my original thread that got me pointed in the right direction. Thanks for the follow up!

Answer (score 2):

Either `@cities` is `nil`, or `@cities[@current_location]` is `nil`.

Figure out which one it is and then find a way to make sure it's populated. :-)

Comment: I believe I did a valid test using p, and neither of them is nil. Is there a better way to do that? Please see the edit in the original text.

Comment: @NoahClark: As you discovered while working with @sepp2k, we were talking about `@current_location` being an invalid key in `@cities`, so that `@cities[@current_location]` is `nil`. That's different from `@current_location` being `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `hash.fetch()` rather than `hash[]`, then you'd get an exception when the key doesn't exist, rather than getting nil.

To debug further, I'd do

```
hash.fetch(key) {raise "couldn't find #{key.inspect} amongst the keys #{hash.keys.inspect}"}
```